# fetch Property on the Basis of Maximum and Minimum Price Laravel 5

Tags: database, controller, laravel-5

Hi I have 2 Dropdown one fro Maximun Price and another one for Minimum Price, I am trying to filter data from Database Suppose I have 4 records with price(20000, 40000, 60000, 80000), When user clicks on 60000 i want to show the less than and equal data so result will come like this(20000, 40000, 60000). **here is my controller**

```
public function max_price()
  {
    $term=60000;
    $display = DB::table('property_details')
                ->where('property_price', '>', '$term')
                ->Where('sale_or_rent', '=', 'sale')
                ->get();

       var_dump($display); 

    if(count($display)!=0)
        {    
          $returnHTML = view('/pages/right_side_area')->with('row', $display)->render();
          return response()->json(array('success' => true, 'html'=>$returnHTML));
        }
        else
        {
        session::flash('status', 'No Records Found!!!');
        $returnHTML = view('/pages/right_side_area')->with('row', $display)->render();
        return response()->json(array('success' => true,   'html'=>$returnHTML));
        }
 }
```

Comment: look at using the `lists()` method to return a flat array of values. Otherwise, whats wrong with your code? Is there a specific error?

Comment: I got the solution... thanx for reply

Answer (score 0):

In my controller, my query was not correct, but now everything is fine

```
//Minimum Price search
  public function min_price()
  {
    $term=Input::get('min');

    $display = DB::table('property_details')
                ->where('property_price', '>=', $term)
                ->Where('sale_or_rent', '=', 'sale')
                ->get();

                //var_dump($display); 
               if(count($display)!=0)
             {    
               $returnHTML = view('/pages/right_side_area')->with('row', $display)->render();
               return response()->json(array('success' => true, 'html'=>$returnHTML));
             }
              else
              {
               session::flash('status', 'No Records Found!!!');
               $returnHTML = view('/pages/right_side_area')->with('row', $display)->render();
               return response()->json(array('success' => true, 'html'=>$returnHTML));
             }
           }    
Hope it will helps other people..
```